# Splitting at specific string from a dataframe column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column called "Spl" with the values below: I am trying to extract the values next to `'name':` strings (some rows have multiple values) but I see the new column generated with the specific location of the memory. I used the below code to extract. Any help how to extract the values after "name:" string is much appreciated.

Column values:

```
'name': 'Chirotherapie', 'name': 'Innen Medizin'
'name': 'Manuelle Medizin'
'name': 'Akupunktur', 'name': 'Chirotherapie', 'name': 'Innen Medizin'
```

Code:

```
df['Spl'] = lambda x: len(x['Spl'].str.split("'name':"))
```

Output:

```
<function <lambda> at 0x0000027BF8F68940>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply do:-

```
df['Spl']=df['Spl'].str.split("'name':").str.len()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do count

```
df['Spl'] = df['Spl'].str.count("'name':")+1
```